# Database schema to map Hotel Amenities from different sources into a uniform format to remove duplicates

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, database-design

I am creating a hotel application that fetches hotel feeds from different sources and store it to database to form a uniform structure and expose API to the mobile application. I am fetching hotels from 3 different sources using python/django app.

Now every hotel source has different sets of amenities for example:

```
Source 1 [Expedia]
    - Free WiFi
    - Hairdryer In Room
    - Cable TV
    - Double Bed
    - Single Bed
    - Fireplace

Source 2 [SomeHotelProvider]
    - WiFi
    - Hairdryer
    - Television
    - and so on
```

So here we have same amenity name with different name (Free WiFi and WiFi ) for example. The only problem is that at the Mobile screen it will display two filter [Free WiFi, Wifi] to filter out the result set. So what is best approach to deal with these duplicate values.

Need a solution to create a mapping table that maps all duplicates to one amenities master table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a person who goes through the amenities and classifies them.

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thanks for the reply, that is the last option in my mind, But would really like if this can be achieved without human efforts as the API pulls thousands of amenities from different hotel providers.

Comment: For remove this problem you need to avoid to create amenities manual. That is give a list of possible values for amenities and choose from it( For future). To avoid it from the already existing data only possible way is @GordonLinoff solution.

Comment: Without a natural language processor that can answer the question "are these two things the same thing?" you can't avoid having manual work involved to classify the various amenities. There are open-source NLPs out there and also 'in the cloud' NLPs (e.g. Google, Amazon) so you might want to try them.

Comment: @dirkgroten . . . Even a natural language processor won't have the right judgement . . . "Cable TV", "Satellite TV", "TV".  Are these the same or different?  Further, I can imagine that amenities might appear in different languages.

Comment: @GordonLinoff true, without training for the specific use case, it wouldn't work probably. And training means first create the labelled data manually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JSONB column so you can accept any type of data. in a hash format.  Then you will have to find duplicate keys and consolidate them.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Then you will have to go through and consolidate duplicate keys (wifi, free wifi, etc).  Unfortunately this can't be done programatically as even if you wrote a perfect program to do this, in the future there might be a new form you did not account for like "included Wifi".